# javascript loaded image is blurry (PNG)

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, canvas, drawimage

I'm having a problem drawing sprites on canvas for a school project.  My code:

```
treeImage = new Image();
treeImage.src = "sprites/treeSprites.png"; 

function rocks() { //to create the rock
  this.x = 1920 * Math.random(); //random location on the width of the field
  this.y = ground[Math.round(this.x/3)]; //ground is an array that stores the height of the ground
  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.rotate(Math.tan((ground[Math.floor(this.x/3)]-ground[Math.floor(this.x/3)+1])/-3));
        //^rotating based on its position on the ground^
    ctx.drawImage(treeImage, 200, 50, 50, 50, -25, -50, 50, 50);
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

len = rockArray.length; //every frame
for (var i = 0;i<len;i++) {
  rockArray[i].draw();
}
```

I only request 50×50px from the image. Exactly outside of the 50×50 there are black lines (which shouldn't interfere because I only request the square within the black lines) but when I draw the rock, the black outlines are visible. (For other reasons, I can't remove the black lines.)

[image]

I'm guessing the image JavaScript stores when I load the image is made blurry, and then when I request that part from the image, the lines around are visible too, as the blur "spreads" the lines into the square I request.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

Comment: It look like it's from the anti-alisassing.

Comment: Are you on some high dpi monitor (like 4k or retina)? Also, try to tound yohr coordinates.

Comment: @Kaiido 1920*1080, which is the size of my canvas too, and i am rounding all the coords now thanks to Ceres' answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false`.

This will make the image sharp instead of smoothed (blurry).

([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled))

Comment: This does indeed make it look better, and it helps me further, but the black outline still is displayed
[link](http://tinypic.com/r/2z68dax/9)

Answer (score 0):

If you draw a vertical line at x=5 and width = 1, the canvas actually draws the line from 4.5 to 5.5 this results in aliasing and a fuzzy line. A quick way to remedy that so it is a solid line is to offset the entire canvas by half a pixel before doing anthing else.

`ctx.translate(-0.5, -0.5);`

([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate))

Comment: this indeed further increases the look, and the pixels now are as sharp as can be, when i remove the rotation, but while the rocks are rotated the problem still occurs (the black lines around the rocks)

Comment: This is true for path strokes, but not for other drawing methods.